# Import CSV into Salesforce (Group Edition) automatically

Tags: data-loader, bulk-api, csv, import

I'd like to import CSV file into Salesforce automatically, e.g. once a day. I can't use Data Loader (Bulk API), because I don't have the needed edition. Is there any other, simple way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use Salesforce **import wizard**. If it is an Standard object you can use directly **Import Account/Contact, Import leads, Import Opportunities** etc.

> You can also use jitterbit dataloader which is available for group edition, Belo it the link for same
>
> https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N300000016ZoVEAU
>
> Or you can enable bulk api then you can use apex data loader.

Comment: you can then check the jitterbit dataloader in the link

Comment: Salesforce import wizard isn't automated and jitterbit costs 1000 USD per moth and that's a huge amount of money for company with four Salesforce users.

Comment: You can contact the support and they can guide you how to enable the BULK API after which you can use apex data loader. note that the bulk api might also be paid.

Comment: So I wrote to Salesforce but they said, that I must upgrade to Professional. At least. I thought that I can use other APIs - REST and SOAP. Do you know about other solution?

Comment: Have you tried data loader for salesforce appexchange app here is the link https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N30000009w8ZBEAY&tab=r

Comment: Yeah. But that's not automated.